# Ruby on rails incorrectly dumps all the postgresql table content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, for-loop

I'm realatively new to ruby on rails and im really having problems with a simple for-loop.

I'm doing this:

Inside **posts_controller.rb**

```
@post = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

Inside **posts/index.html.erb** (the view related to the controller)

```
<%= @post.each do |post| %>

  <%= link_to post.title, post %>
  <br>"Published "
  <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
  <br>by user.email
  <%= post.user.email %>

  <br><br>
<% end %>
```

But the output is (I copied just the important part)

```
primer pst de ET 
"Published " 1 day 
by user.email cacaca@gmail.com 

primer post de cocina 
"Published " 1 day 
by user.email cacaca@gmail.com 

[#<Post id: 14, title: "La tercera es la vencida", content: "<p><span style=\"color:#ffffff;\"><span style=\"backg...", created_at: "2018-12-23 03:07:41", updated_at: "2018-12-23 03:07:41", user_id: 1, category: "rangos de aventurero", thumbnail: "img2", status: "pending">, #<Post id: 13, title: "segundo post con status", content: "<p><span style=\"color:#2ecc71;\">ahora &acute;si qu...", created_at: "2018-12-23 03:05:32", updated_at: "2018-12-23 03:05:32", user_id: 1, category: "Endless Tower", thumbnail: nil, status: nil>, #<Post id: 12, title: "Segundo post COCINA", content: "<p>Esto es el primer post COCINA con im&aacute;gen...", created_at: "2018-12-23 02:53:06", updated_at: "2018-12-23 02:53:06", user_id: 1, category: "Cocina", thumbnail: nil, status: nil>, #<Post id: 11, title: "primer post con status", content: "gtgtrhtgr", created_at: "2018-12-23 02:31:51", updated_at: "2018-12-23 02:31:51", user_id: 1, category: "", thumbnail: nil, status: nil>, #<Post id: 10, title: "primer post economía", content: "f3rggg ecoooooo", created_at: "2018-12-23 02:19:42", updated_at: "2018-12-23 02:19:42", user_id: 1, category: "Economía", thumbnail: nil, status: nil>, #<Post id: 9, title: "primer pst de ET", content: "ET SE HACE UNA VEZ A LA SEMAN", created_at: "2018-12-23 02:17:04", updated_at: "2018-12-23 02:17:04", user_id: 1, category: "Endless Tower", thumbnail: nil, status: nil>, #<Post id: 8, title: "primer post de cocina", content: "wfowrffmweew COCINAAAAAA", created_at: "2018-12-23 02:00:39", updated_at: "2018-12-23 02:00:39", user_id: 1, category: "Cocina", thumbnail: nil, status: nil>] 
AQUÍ TERMINA EL RENDER INDIVIDUAL
```

So it dumps all the database content at the end and I realy don't know why.

I clearly don't want the user to see the table content but I don't know whats wrong with the code above.

I know it's probably a very basic question, but i can't find the answer yet. Please help me.

Thanks for yor help :)

EDIT: here is the full controller code

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  # La siguiente línea establece que se llamará al método <find_post>
  # antes de llamar a los métodos <show>, <edit>, <update>, <destroy>
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :stablish_categories_and_thumbnail

  def index
    @post = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category, :status, :thumbnail)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def stablish_categories_and_thumbnail
    # Esto es lo que hay que ir rellenando luego con las categorías finales
    @categories = ['Cocina',
                   'Endless Tower',
                   'Economía',
                   'rangos de aventurero']

    @thumbnails_list = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4']
  end

end
```

Comment: show full controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `=` sign from your **posts/index.html.erb**:

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= @post.each do |post| %>
```

`<%= ... %>` will evaluate the statement/block and print the result. `<% ... %>` will only evaluate and not print it. For example -

`<%= a = 5 %>` will assign and print '5' on the page.

`<% a = 5 %>` will only assign '5' to the local variable `a` but not print it.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. What does de '=' do in this context?